# Specifying self parameter in Python UML class diagrams

Tags: python, uml

I know that there is no official UML standarts for Python but if I want to specify parameters in methods of class should I specify `self` parameter? Or consider it passed as default? Will be thankful for any proc and cons of using `self` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a class diagram, class attributes such as self.x, self.y, etc. are listed in their own section, after the class name, but before the class methods. It is not necessary to add the self in front of every attribute, so you can just drop it.

When listing class methods, you normally only list their signature (name, parameter names and types) and return type. The class attributes that are used inside of those methods is not listed. An example of an entry in each section would be:

```
Rectangle

width: float
height: float

area(): float
```

Note that the visibility of class attributes and methods is handled differently in Python. There are no private or protected class attributes or methods in Python; everything is public. Instead of using keywords such as private, protected, and public to signal visibility, the name is used to convey intentions regarding visibility. The general consensus is that:

- class attributes and methods with a name that starts with an underscore or a double 
  underscore (name mangling is applied) are not part of the public interface
- all other class attributes and methods are deemed part of the public interface

So, if you want indicate that the width and height attributes shouldn't be accessed from outside of this class, you would adapt the previous example in the following way:

```
Rectangle

_width: float
_height: float

area(): float
_a_private_method(): None
```

**To answer your question directly: no reason to use 'self' in a class diagram.**

Comment: I'd use the UML notation for public/private (+/-) instead. So your model is independent of the language. A code generation would put an underscore in front of the name.